# Why aren't two of my rectangles showing up?

Tags: processing, rect

```java
void setup(){
  size(100,100);
  fill(255,255,255);
  rect(0,0,50,50);
  rect(50,50,100,0);
  rect(50,50,0,100);
  rect(50,50,100,100);
}

void draw(){

}

void mousePressed(){
  if ((mouseX <= 50) && (mouseY <= 50)){
    fill(random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255));
    rect(0,0,50,50);
  }
  if ((mouseX >= 50) && (mouseY >= 50)){
    fill(random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255));
    rect(50,50,100,100);
  }
  if ((mouseX >= 50) && (mouseY <= 50)){
    fill(random(0,255), random(0,255), random(0,255));
    rect(50,50,100,0);
  }
  if ((mouseX <= 50) && (mouseY >= 50)){
    fill (random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255));
    rect(50,50,0,100);
  }
}
```

Hello, I am a new programmer recently introduced to Processing 3. When I run this code, 2 squares are missing (top right and bottom left). I've reviewed the code but I do not see any errors. If someone knows what is wrong in the code, please let me know.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/rect_.html) for the `rect()` function:

> By default, the first two parameters set the location of the upper-left corner, the third sets the width, and the fourth sets the height.

Now let's look at the two lines of code you're having trouble with:

```java
rect(50,50,100,0);
```

This rectangle will be `0` pixels tall, so you won't see it. Similarly:

```java
rect(50,50,0,100);
```

This rectangle will be `0` pixels wide, so you won't see it.

I'm guessing that you're thinking that the last two parameters are the lower-right corner, but that's not the case by default. Of course, you could change this using the [`rectMode()`](https://processing.org/reference/rectMode_.html) function:

```java
rectMode(CORNERS);
```